# .net core WPF Dependency injection

Tags: wpf, .net-core, dependency-injection, wpf-core

I am new to WPF, I have created a simple WPF application that has a button, which on clicked will fetch data from database and give the output in textbox.

I have a issue in Dependency Injection, there is AppDBContext class for database, and logMessageService.cs which has the functionality for fetching data from DB.

```
private readonly ILogMessageService Service;

    public MainWindow(ILogMessageService service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Service = service;
    }
```

I was given an error "No matching constructor found on type 'MainWindow'"

How to perform dependency injection in WPF?

Comment: Hi. What was your solution? I'm using the MS DI in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and would like the DI to handle service creation rather than pulling the services out of Services in each views constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use MVVM and create a MainWindowViewModel which you create in the Public MainWindow() constructor.  The ViewModel can then either initialise the service itself, or your MainWindow constructor can initialise it and pass it as part of the constructor to the new view model.

```
Public MainWindow()
{
    InitialiseComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(service);
}
```

Or

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

...
</Window>
```

And

```
Public Class MainWindowViewModel
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.